# Swift arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array of strings.

```
    var animals = ["cats 99", "dogs 42", "chimps 45", "moose 98"]
    var excludeAnimalArray = ["chimps", "dogs"]
```

Output should be "cats 99", "moose 98". Please keep in mind there is no way to tell what the number next to the animal will be.

Comment: Should the result be sorted by the number value? Or it is just a coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter `filter`:

```
let result = animals.filter { animal in
    !excludeAnimalArray.contains { animal.hasPrefix($0) }
}
```

Comment: There we go!  Nice :)

Comment: You can add `let set = Set(excludeAnimalArray)` before your code and then use `set` instead of `excludeAnimalArray`. It will make the execution faster.

Comment: Solved...So fresh and so clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's fast answer, though I'm sure there's a less imperative / more purely functional way of doing it too.

```
var animals = ["cats 99", "dogs 42", "chimps 45", "moose 98"]
var excludeAnimalArray = ["chimps", "dogs"]

var result = animals.filter{
    animal in
    var include = true
    excludeAnimalArray.forEach{ if animal.hasPrefix($0){ include=false } }
    return include
}

print(result) //["cats 99", "moose 98"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
animals.sort = {
    // return sort logic here
}
```

You can see examples [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/sort-and-sorted/).